# hibernate3:hbm2ddl exception

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm attempting to get an 3 year old project to build and there is little documentation and nobody who previously work on it is still around.

I'm getting the following exception when trying to run mvn -X hibernate3:hbm2ddl

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is 
required to use

hibernate version - 3.5.4-Final

This is the config for the hibernate plugin..

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <componentProperties>
                    <drop>true</drop>
                    <configurationfile>src/main/conf/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                    <propertyfile>src/main/resources/database.properties</propertyfile>
                </componentProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the hibernate annotations jar to your dependencies?

Comment: I tried added it to the plugin dependencies.  I added hibernate-commons-annotations. There is not commons annotations for version 3.5.4-Final. I tried a few specific ones but I ran into other issues. Is there a specific version I should try?

Comment: Use hibernate-annotations with same version as hibernate-core you are using.  <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId><version>${hibernate-core-version}</version> </dependency>... but I don't think that this is the problem. Looks like a hibernate bootstrap configuration. Add the dependency and paste any new issue

Comment: I added it to the plugin dependencies. It was already there as a build dependency. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!  Thanks to: https://stephou.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/creating-a-database-using-hbm2ddl-and-maven/

I had to add this to the plugin config.

```
              <components>
               <component>
                <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
               </component>
              </components>
```